# Converting image as vector arrays for graph plotting

Tags: python

I have a segmented image here and I wanted to convert the white parts into points and plot it to a graph.

[image: Segmented image]

[image: So it will look something like this as plotted points]

Is there any suggestions as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: How do you calculate the density of the white areas in order to place the points? Because areas that have some more white pixels than others, have more points near them.

Comment: The image of 'points' that was shown just under the segmented image was actually the desired result that I would like. I am unsure how to calculate and convert the density of the areas to generate the points, hence my question. Sorry about any confusions.